# How to fetch the full search result of a windows indexed file search in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, indexing

First, some background on the topic:
I'm currently working on analyzing some big syslog log-files (the smaller one of the two being 48GB) using powershell. To do this, I already instructed the Windows indexing feature to specifically check the folder I store the log file in and I successfully tested it with a search using the built-in file explorer. I want to extract all the logs that contain a certain string (e.g. dstip=IP).

The Problem I'm facing is that I see no way to extract the exact lines that match my searchstring from the indexed search.

I can read the "AutoSummary", which is the "Preview" shown in file explorer, using powershell, but there seems to be no function to read the whole found content line by line. I do see all file attributes (path, filename, etc.), but the file content is what eludes me and I could not find a specific question already asked for this.

Here's my current code for better understanding:

```
# source: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/build-a-query-to-search-the-windows-index-from-powershell/

$search_string = 'dstip=10.0.0.1'
$search_path = 'C:\Path\to\my\directory'

$sql_query = "SELECT System.Search.AutoSummary, System.ItemUrl FROM SYSTEMINDEX WHERE SCOPE = '$search_path' AND Contains(System.Search.Contents,'$search_string')"

$provider = "Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties='Application=Windows';"
$adapter = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter -argument $sql_query, $provider
$ds = New-Object System.Data.DataSet

# data is fetched by using the oleDBDataAdapter and DataSet objects. 
# The adapter is created by specifying a “provider” (which says where the data will come from) and a 
# SQL statement (which says what is being requested).

if ($adapter.Fill($ds)) { 
    $ds.Tables[0] | select-object System.Search.AutoSummary, System.ItemUrl  | format-list 
}
else {
    echo "send help" 
}
```

Comment: Pipe the file paths to [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.3) . `...| Select-string -Pattern [Regex]::Escape('dstip=10.0.0.1')`.

Comment: Typing on my phone ATM, will post an answer tomorrow with code to execute your search in **Explorer** so you have visual confirmation and pipe the results to Select-String.

Comment: @KeithMiller Wouldn't that only cause the script to go normally through all the files again (not through the indexed files)? This process takes for the ~48GB file around 9+ hours.

Comment: As far as I know, and understand your question, if you want to locate content within the file, you have to searrch the content. The index only tells you the search string is*somewhere* in the file and thus ensures you're only searching those files that contain your search string. I'm unclear as to what you want from the content -- is there other info in the lines that contain your search term?

Comment: @KeithMiller Yes and I realize I haven't been as clear as I could. I'm reading the log file to find out which hosts are connecting to a certain destination IP, which is why I'm searching the "dstip=10.0.0.1" string within the file. Once I could "grep" the log file for lines that only contain the dstip I am looking for, I am processing the result further.

Comment: However, I found something interesting when just fuzzing around with select-string: I have reason to believe that select-string already uses the windows index as the following command finished in about 5 minutes for the 48 GB log (which would make 160MB/s, still in the realm of possibilities with SSDs, I guess...):
```select-string -Path $syslog_file -Pattern $pat > filtered_syslog.txt```

Also, it created a 717MB file of as filtered_syslog.txt that at least only contains the correct dstip.
However, I couldn't find any documentation on whether or not ``select-string`` uses the index or not

Comment: I doubt it. I think the index is a higher-order ,creation of the Windows Shell, not natively available as a . Net building block.

Comment: Given that the amount of data encourages optimization, I'm curious to know if your**Explorer** search limited irself to searching only the content property, i.e. `Content:"dstip=10.0.0.1" ` or if not, does doing so seem to improve search speed?

Comment: @KeithMiller No, in explorer I even searched for "10.0.0.1" (without dstip) and the result turned up immediately. However, the shown result in explorer is only the "Preview" and doesn't show more (so it might just stop for this reason after the first find).

Comment: I get that Explorer search doesn't give you all the lines, and I just read your answer -- fascinating!!!  My thought process, which shoud  be valid given yowasur success with testing the index, was to have the script open an Explorer window, execute the search, and then pass the results to Select-String to extract the level of detail you need. I'm going to post a supplemental answer to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have found the solution, although I found no documentation on the behavior.

Judging after testing my scenario before and after indexing my log file using the built-in file-indexing feature of windows, `Select-String` does indeed seem to use the Windows index database. Before I added the log file directory to the "to be indexed" directories, the script took about 8 to 9 hours to finish.

After I configured the directory to be indexed by Windows, it takes about 10~15 minutes. As I was sceptical about the results, I compared them to the results of the longer runs and could confirm that the results are indeed correct.

The indexing options can be directly opened through the start menu, searching for "index".

Thanks for the food for thought @KeithMiller!

Answer (score 0):

Glad to hear of your success with testing the relationship between indexing and `Select-String`. Here's an alternate way of executing a search that takees advantage of indexing -- using Explorer itself. It involves using the properties and methods of the[`Shell.Application`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell) com object.

```
###   To keep example simple, close all Explorer windows
###   before running this code.

$search_string   = 'dstip=10.0.0.1'
$search_path     = 'C:\Path\to\my\directory'

$shell           = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application

# Open an Explorer window to the search target
$shell.Open($search_path)

# Don't let the code get ahead of Exploer
While (!($shell.Windows().Count)) {sleep -m 50}

# Get the new window
$NewWin = @($shell.Windows())[0]

# Execute the search
$NewWin.Document.FilterView($search_string)

# Wait for search to complete
While ($NewWin.ReadyState -ne 4) {sleep -m 50}

# Pipe search results to Select-Sttring
$Results = @($NewWin.Document.Folder.Items()).Path | Get-Item | Select-String -Pattern [Regex]::Escape($search_string)

$Results | Get-Member
```